# Sugar ORM: How to display values

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sugarorm

I use Sugar ORM for Android Development via Android Studio.

But I think I have a quite similar question.
How can I display one/multiple result queries as String or int?
My entity looks like this:

```
public class PersonsDatabase extends SugarRecord<PersonsSelection>{
String adultText, childText;
int adultCount, childCount;

public PersonsDatabase()
{

}
public PersonsDatabase(String adultText, String childText, int adultCount, int childCount)
{
    this.adultText = adultText;
    this.childText = childText;

    this.adultCount = adultCount;
    this.childCount = childCount;

    this.save();
}
```

}

It saves correctly. But when I want to display like this:

```
public class PersonsSelection extends Activity {

ListView list;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_persons_selection);

    PersonsDatabase personsDatabase = new PersonsDatabase("1 Adult","No Childs",1,0);
    List<PersonsDatabase> personsList = PersonsDatabase.findWithQuery(PersonsDatabase.class,"Select adult_Text from PERSONS_DATABASE");

    list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<PersonsDatabase>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, personsList));
}
```

}

I get something like: *PACKAGENAME*.PersonsDatabase@4264c038
But I want the values that I wrote in the constructor.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs on `ArrayAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html):

> However the TextView is referenced, it will be filled with the toString() of each object in the array. You can add lists or arrays of custom objects. **Override the toString() method of your objects to determine what text will be displayed for the item in the list.**

In short: just override the `toString()` method in your `PersonsDatabase` class to return the desired textual respresentation.

Alternatively:

> To use something other than TextViews for the array display, for instance, ImageViews, or to have some of data besides toString() results fill the views, override `getView(int, View, ViewGroup)` to return the type of view you want.

(again from the docs). Plenty of examples out there on how to go about doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Simply override the toString() method.
In that method, return whichever database value you want to retrieve.

In my case, I returned a variable name that I needed (i.e. message) :

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return message;
}
```